# Do it right the first time > Infopath Info

Tags: infopath, forms-services

Okay,

I have seen many variation of infopath form designing method. From SP list > directly design a form (bad idea for deploying to multiple sites or farm).

What is the good approach to utilize in order to make it right for the first time and use the same method. (Should we use form library per site collection? Should the designing piece consist of content type instead of list)

Are there any good article or blog on this? I googled it but nothing good is seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single answer here. Getting form design correct is really going to depend on the requirements. In some cases, designing a single list and customizing the form will be the answer for a small process. For larger processes, designing a form that is deployed as a content type in a site collection will work, for other cases, you will need to deploy the form to the farm as an administrator approved template. You cannot regulate all forms to be deployed in a single manner. You will have to work with what works best for the particular process or business need that you have.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to confirm with pros to make sure I am taking the right approach. Thanks